# Merge sort in python doesnt update the array after sorting

Tags: python, sorting, recursion, merge

```
ab = [5, 89, 23, 9]

def mergsort(array):        
    mid = len(array) / 2
    if mid > 0:
        print (array)
        mergsort(array[:mid])
        mergsort(array[mid:])
        print(array)
        merg(array)
    return array

def merg(array):
    print (array)
    mid = len(array)//2
    left = array[:mid]
    right = array[mid:]
    i = j = k = 0

    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
        if left[i] < right[j]:
            array[k] = left[i]
            i+=1

        else:
            array[k] = right[j]
            j+=1
        k+=1

    while i < len(left):    
        array[k]=left[i]
        i+=1
        k+=1

    while j < len(right):    
        array[k] = right[j]
        j+=1
        k+=1
    print (array)

mergsort(ab)
print (ab)
```

The merge function sort the array given and the array is updated. But in the next recursion the array going into the `merg` function is not the mutated array.

In the example, first sorting happens and `[5,89]` and `[23,9]` are sorted as `[5,89]` and `[9,23]` but the merged input in the next recursion is `[5,89,23,9]` instead of `[5,89,9,23]`.

I am unable to find any reason as mutating the array should affect the parent array.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is with the recursive calls:

```
    mergsort(array[:mid])
    mergsort(array[mid:])
```

the results of these calls are not recorded - so when we continue, it's done with the same original unsorted array.

The fix:

```
def mergsort(array):     
    if len(array) == 1:
        return array
    mid=len(array)/2
    left = mergsort(array[:mid])  # save into a parameter
    right = mergsort(array[mid:])  # save into a parameter
    return merge(left, right)  #  use the previous two
```

The second issue is actually the same kind of issue only with:

```
def merg(array)
```

the merge operation is done between two arrays, which means that two distinct arrays should be sent to this function, otherwise there is no recollection of `mid` from the function `mergesort()` and declaring `mid` to be `length/2` treats the whole array and not the specific two parts that we intend to merge. The idea behind the logic inside this function is correct but should be done, as I mentioned, on two "distinct" arrays.

Last problem is the in-place swap which is incorrectly done, for example in:

```
array[k]=right[j]
```

by doing do, we erase the element at `array[k]`!

The fix:

```
def merge(left, right):
    if  len(left+right) < 2:
        return left+right
    res = []
    i = j = 0
    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
        if left[i] < right[j]:
            res.append(left[i])
            i += 1
        elif j < len(right):
            res.append(right[j])
            j += 1        
    while i < len(left):
        res.append(left[i])
        i += 1
    while j < len(right):
        res.append(right[j])
        j += 1
    return res
```

After applying both fixes and running:

```
print mergsort(ab)
```

The output is:

```
[5, 9, 23, 89]
```

as required.

Comment: Hey.. thanks for that clear explanation. But one doubt which I have is, as I muate the list variable in the merge function, wont that update the array in merge sort automatically. I can see that it doesnt happen,It doesnt happen . But dont understand why?

Comment: @user32175 please read my explanation again, pay special attention to the part that talks about what you're passing to `merge` and how does `merge` "knows" which are the left and right parts it should process.